# How to prevent an image folder from being overwritten when I redeploy my website on Azure with .NET?

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I developed [this](https://denticare.azurewebsites.net/) website. The team members come from SQLServer and its images are stored in the wwwroot folder. Whenever I republish the project, the subfolder where the images are stored get overwritten and I lose the images.

How can I keep the images that is linked to data stored in the database safe from being overwritten when I redeploy the project?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You did not mention how you're deploying the app

Answer (score 0):

In the publish settings, uncheck "Remove additional files at destination".

[image]